# Shell script linux, validating integer

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, grep

This code is for check if a character is a integer or not (i think). I'm trying to understand what this means, I mean... each part of that line, checking the GREP man pages, but it's really difficult for me. I found it on the internet. If anyone could explain me the part of the grep... what means each thing put there:

`echo $character | grep -Eq '^(\+|-)?[0-9]+$'`

Thanks people!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Analyse this regex:

```
'^(\+|-)?[0-9]+$'

^ - Line Start
(\+|-)? - Optional + or - sign at start
[0-9]+ - One or more digits
$ - Line End
```

Overall it matches strings like `+123` or `-98765` or just `9`

Here `-E` is for extended regex support and `-q` is for quiet in grep command.

**PS:** btw you don't need `grep` for this check and can do this directly in pure bash:

```
re='^(\+|-)?[0-9]+$'
[[ "$character" =~ $re ]] && echo "its an integer"
```

Comment: Thanks man... im trying to understand all this stuff in linux, i'm very new in this.. i'll keep on trying

Comment: Here i found this, for anyone who need it: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17046.html

Answer (score 1):

I like this cheat sheet for regex: 
http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

It is very useful, you could easily analyze the

'^(+|-)?[0-9]+$'

as

- ^: Line must begin with...
- (): grouping
- \: ESC character (because + means something ... see below)
- +|-: plus OR minus signs
- ?: 0 or 1 repetation
- [0-9]: range of numbers from 0-9
- +: one or more repetation
- $: end of line (no more characters allowed)

so it accepts like: -312353243 or +1243 or 5678 
but do not accept:   3 456 or 6.789 or 56$ (as dollar sign).